# Can filter() contain two conditions?

Tags: python, list, filter, functional-programming

can i use filter() to include multiple conditions? for example, if I have a code like this.

```
nums = [3, 7, 10, 29, 39, 55, 67, 77, 107]
res = list(filter(lambda x: x > 60, nums))
print(res)
```

how can I use filter to include numbers greater than 60 and numbers that are less than 20?

Comment: Have you heard of the `and` operator? (Or chained comparisons, but `and` is more important to know.)

Comment: so then {lambda x: x > 60 and < 20, nums}?

Comment: `s/and/or` then yes

Comment: (Spotting a potential future problem.) Be careful when translating human language into logic - while there are numbers greater than 60 and numbers less than 20, there are no numbers that are greater than 60 and less than 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using filter but a list comprehension

```
[x for x in nums if x < 20 or x > 60]
```

You can do the same thing with the filter but it will just be cumbersome

```
list(filter(lambda x: x < 20 or x > 60, nums))
```

Comment: I had a feeling a list comprehension would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

[Chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) with a list comprehension may be appropriate here:

```
[x for x in nums if not 20 <= x <= 60]
```